# dotCover filter with command line

Tags: c#, dotcover, resharper-8.0

What is the correct way to call dotCover command runner passing it several filters?

I've tried the following but it only excludes the first assembly:

```
dotcover c /TargetExecutable="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MsTest.exe" /TargetArguments="/testcontainer:c:\dev\SampleProject\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll" /Output="c:\temp\Snapshot1.dcvr" /Filters="-:Assembly1, -:Assembly2"
```

it ignores anything after **,** in filter tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it with the following:

```
dotcover c /TargetExecutable="c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MsTest.exe" /TargetArguments="/testcontainer:c:\dev\SampleProject\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll" /Output="c:\temp\Snapshot1.dcvr" /Filters="-:Assembly1;-:Assembly2"
```

Instead of comma and space as the separator, try it with semicolon.

Comment: that works thank you so much. I wish JetBrains page had this info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another example as this was such a pain:

```
dotCover.exe dotnet --output=AppCoverageReport.html --reportType=HTML  --Filters="-:Company.Base.*;-:FluentValidation*;-:Dapper*;-:Spekt*;-:HealthChecks*"  --AttributeFilters="System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute;" -- test "Company.User.sln"
```