# how to use "Dotnet dotcover test --dcFilters" command to exclude certain namespaces from code coverage

Tags: .net-core, nunit, dotcover

I am using dotnet dotcover test command in my gitlab-ci.yml to get the code coverage.
I have included dotcover dotnetclitool version 2020.3.3 in my unit tests solution for this command to execute during the pipeline test stage.
But i am not able to successfully exclude certain classes(under a specific namespace/folder) from the code coverage results. My solution structure is as follows:

1. source folder

   - AClient.Repository.csproj

     - Extensions folder

       > AClientExt.cs
     - Models folder

       > ModelA.cs

       > ModelB.cs
     - Repository folder

       > RepoA.cs

       > RepoB.cs
2. tests folder

   - AClient.Repository.UnitTests.csproj

     - RepositoryTests

       > RepoATests.cs

Now the code coverage includes both the solutions and I want to exclude the following namespaces:

```
AClient.Repository.Extensions.*
AClient.Repository.Models.*
AClient.Repository.Tests.*
```

I am running this command and it is not able to exclude the filters correctly so could someone please help me figure out correct usage of dcFilters:
[image: code coverage]

Answer (score 7):

I finally resolved it like this:

```
run-testCoverage:
  stage: dotnet-test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  before_script:
    - cd tests/AClient.Repository.UnitTests
  script:
    - dotnet restore -v d
    - dotnet dotcover test --dcReportType=HTML --dcOutput=../../coverage/AppCoverageReport.html --dcFilters="+:AClient.Repository;-:type=AClient.Repository.Extensions.*;-:type=AClient.Repository.Models.*;-:type=AClient.Repository.UnitTests"
```

This is the answer that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6208644/11731377

Comment: Thanks for this, a few other solutions as this ended up being a pain! https://stackoverflow.com/q/34955885/495455